# Filter and export data in .csv

Tags: powershell, csv, registry

I need a few instructions to scroll a list of servers, remotely edit some registry keys for each server and save the output of each registry key update in a .csv file.
I tried my scripts and they seem to work but I'm not able to filter the results and save only (and exactly) what I need in the .csv:

**Script 1:**

```
$Invocation = (Get-Variable MyInvocation -Scope 0).Value
$LocalDir = Split-Path $Invocation.MyCommand.Path
$Computers = Get-Content $LocalDir'\HostsList.txt'
$Results = foreach ($Computer in $Computers) {
    Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Computer -FilePath $LocalDir'\autologon_editor.ps1' -ArgumentList $Computer
}
$Results | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Path $LocalDir'\ResultsAutologon.csv'
```

**Script 2:**

```
Param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,
    ValueFromPipeline=$true)]
    [string[]]$Computer
)
$Path = 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon'
$Property1 = 'DefaultUserName'
$Property2 = 'DefaultPassword'
$Value1 = 'NewUserName-new4'
$Value2 = 'NewPassword-new4'
if (Test-Connection -ComputerName $Computer -Count 1 -Quiet) {
    try {
        Set-ItemProperty -Path $Path -Name $Property1 -Value $Value1 -ErrorAction 'Stop'
        Set-ItemProperty -Path $Path -Name $Property2 -Value $Value2 -ErrorAction 'Stop'
        $Status = 'Username and password set ok'
    } catch {
        $Status = 'Username or password set ko'
    }
} else {   
    $Status = 'Unreachable'
}
Get-ItemProperty -Path $Path
RUNDLL32.EXE USER32.DLL,UpdatePerUserSystemParameters ,1 ,True
$Properties = @{            
    'Computer' = $Computer;
    'Status'   = $Status         
}
$Record = New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property $Properties
```

**Issue**

My filter is not working: the .csv does not contain the fields "Computer" and "Status", but the following list:

> "Userinit", "LegalNoticeText", "Shell", "LegalNoticeCaption", "DebugServerCommand", "ForceUnlockLogon", "ReportBootOk", "VMApplet", "AutoRestartShell", "PowerdownAfterShutdown", "ShutdownWithoutLogon", "Background", "PreloadFontFile", "PasswordExpiryWarning", "CachedLogonsCount", "WinStationsDisabled", "PreCreateKnownFolders", "DisableCAD", "scremoveoption", "ShutdownFlags", "AutoLogonSID", "LastUsedUsername", "DefaultUserName", "DefaultPassword", "PSPath", "PSParentPath", "PSChildName", "PSDrive", "PSProvider", "PSComputerName", "RunspaceId", "PSShowComputerName"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Script 2 (which I assume is autologon_editor.ps1) is not currently outputting `$Record`. However I suspect it is instead returning the output from this command:

```
Get-ItemProperty -Path $Path
```

Which I'm not sure is needed.

I suggest removing the above command and then modifying the end of your script to this:

```
RUNDLL32.EXE USER32.DLL,UpdatePerUserSystemParameters ,1 ,True
$Properties = @{            
    'Computer'=$Computer;
    'Status'=$Status         
}                                       
New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property $Properties
```

This will return the result of the `New-Object` command (the object) to the pipeline, which will in turn make it the output of the `Invoke-Command`.

Comment: It still doesn't work completely; many fields don't appear now, but in addition to "Computer" and "Status" I find "PSComputerName","RunspaceId" and "PSShowComputerName" fields in my csv.

Comment: Those fields are being added by `Invoke-Command`. They are helpful if you run against multiple computers as you can then see which result came from which computer. To exclude those you need to filter your results after the Invoke-Command. E.g: `$Results | Select Computer,Status | Export-Csv ..`

Comment: Great, now it works as I expected! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

For a common solution, see [`Union-Object`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44429084/1701026) for [Not all properties displayed](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44428189/1701026):

`$Results | Union | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Path $LocalDir'\ResultsAutologon.csv`