# Traversing JSON object only get the first 2 values

Tags: json, powershell

I'm trying to write some code in PowerShell v5.1 that recurses through a parsed JSON object to get its property names. An example JSON object is below:

```json
{
    "str1": "Hello World!",
    "strings": {
        "strA": "Foo!",
        "strB": "Bar!"
    },
    "others": {
        "myBool": true,
        "myInt": 42
    }
}
```

First I read and parse the object into a `PSObject`:

```bsh
$jsonString = '{"str1": "Hello World!", "strings":{"strA": "Foo!","strB": "Bar!"}, "others":{"myBool": true,"myInt": 42}}'
$json = $jsonString | ConvertFrom-Json
```

Next I can use `$json.PSobject.properties.name` to get a list of all the top-level property names:

```
PS> $json.PSobject.properties.name
str1
strings
others
```

However, if I use `$json.PSobject.properties.value`, I only see the first **two** values output:

```
PS> $json.PSobject.properties.value
Hello World!

strA strB
---- ----
Foo! Bar!
```

I would expect to see the `others` property included here too. Is there a reason I'm not seeing it?

Comment: This is the formatting subsystem interferring with your output - try outputting the in reverse: `@($json.PSobject.Properties)[2..0].value` :-) Pipe to `Format-List` to see all properties

Comment: Alternatively output each value separately to `Out-Default`: `$json.PSobject.properties.value | % { $_ | Out-Default }`.

Comment: This is because the properties of the objects in the pipeline are not aligned. See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44428189/not-all-properties-displayed/44429084#44429084. Try: `$json.PSobject.properties.value |` [`union`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44429084/1701026)