# Printing Powershell array properties in do/until loop displays blank lines after first iteration of loop

Tags: arrays, powershell, psobject

I am trying to display unique values from each column in an array that is generated from a CSV file.

CSV file contains:

```
ENV,RELEASE,SERVERNAME
DEVL,2008,winhost01
DEVL,2008,winhost02
DEVL,2014,winhost03
DEVL,2016,winhost04
TEST,2008,winhost05
TEST,2014,winhost06
PROD,2008,winhost07
PROD,2014,winhost08
PROD,2014,winhost09
PROD,2014,winhost10
```

Expected output:

```
ENV 
--- 
DEVL
TEST
PROD

RELEASE
---
2008
2014
2016

SERVERNAME
---
winhost01
winhost02
..etc..
winhost10
```

I go through each property in the array printing off the values. I get the first column's values in the first loop, but every column after that just prints an empty line (16 empty lines to be exact).

```
$arrayin = Import-Csv "Documents\Powershell\test.csv";
$cols = $arrayin[0].psobject.properties.name;
$i = 0;
do {
    $arrayin | Select-Object -Property $cols[$i] -Unique;
    $i++;
} until ($i -eq $cols.count)
```

Actual output:

```
ENV 
--- 
DEVL
TEST
PROD
...16 empty lines follow...
```

How can I display the other array properties (columns?) instead of empty lines?

Comment: @PetSerAl, +1 as this is the correct answer but requires an explanation: In Joey's function all objects are appended to the pipeline without output them, like you do with using `FT` (`Format-Table`) or `Write-Host`. At the end, PowerShell releases the whole pipeline but only cares about the property (`ENV`) defined in the first object of the pipeline, see also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44428189/not-all-properties-displayed/44429084#44429084

Comment: @PetSerAl I suggest expanding your comment into an answer, for the sake of future visitors.

Comment: Thank you! PetSerAl's answer was even shorter than i expected. iRon, thank you for the explanation, that really helps.