# PowerShell HashSet with InvariantCultureIgnoreCase contains still case sensitive

Tags: powershell

Why is the second contains returning false?

```
PS C:\Users\s> $filesToExclude = New-Object 'System.Collections.Generic.HashSet[string]([StringComparer]::InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)'
PS C:\Users\s> $filesToExclude.Add("WHATEVER")
True
PS C:\Users\s> $filesToExclude.Contains("whatever")
False
PS C:\Users\s> $filesToExclude.Contains("WHATEVER")
True
```

Comment: `([StringComparer]::InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)` is _not_ part of the type name. Change to `New-Object 'System.Collections.Generic.HashSet[string]' -ArgumentList ([StringComparer]::InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)`

Comment: Remove the single quotes, just: `$filesToExclude = New-Object System.Collections.Generic.HashSet[String]([StringComparer]::InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)`

Comment: Both of these work, thanks! I should stick to C# :)

Answer (score 4):

The syntax you're currently using with `New-Object` is off - type name and constructor arguments are to be passed as separate arguments to separate parameters - which results in the `StringComparer` part simply being ignored completely by PowerShell.

```
# works in PowerShell 2.0 and up
$hashset = New-Object -TypeName 'System.Collections.Generic.HashSet[String]' -ArgumentList ([StringComparer]::InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)

# works in PowerShell 5.0 and up
$hashset = [System.Collections.Generic.HashSet[String]]::new([StringComparer]::InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
```

---