# How to execute several cmdlets in powershell script?

Tags: powershell, powershell-core

I have written this script to get some information about my Virtual Machine. When I execute this script the last two cmdlets (lines) don't execute, but when I execute them alone they run properly.

```
Get-CimInstance Win32_LogicalDisk -Filter "DriveType=3" | Select-Object DeviceID, SystemName, 
@{n='Size (GB)'; e={$_.Size / 1GB -as [int]}}, 
@{n='Freespace (GB)'; e={$_.Freespace / 1GB -as [int]}};
$TotalMemory = (Get-CimInstance Win32_OperatingSystem).TotalVisibleMemorySize / (1024*1024)
$UsedMemory = (Get-CimInstance Win32_OperatingSystem).FreePhysicalMemory / (1024*1024)
$TotalMemory = [math]::Round($TotalMemory,2)
$UsedMemory = [math]::Round($UsedMemory,2)
$TotalMemory
$UsedMemory
Get-CimInstance Win32_Processor | Select-Object -Property NumberOfCores;
Get-CimInstance Win32_Processor | Measure-Object -Property LoadPercentage -Sum | Select-Object Sum;
```

What is the problem?
Any comments would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question has been asked a million times.  Format-table is being implicitly run, and it doesn't handle different sets of columns well.  All the objects are there.  You can pipe the whole script to format-list.  You can put get-date at the very beginning.  A known object with a format file at the beginning fixes it.  You can output more than 4 properties with the first object.  I tried to ask for a warning to be added a while ago:  [format-table should at least warn when it doesn't display properties #7871](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/7871)

Looks like out-gridview has similar struggles:  [Not all properties displayed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44428189/not-all-properties-displayed)

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be one of PowerShell's weird quirks. I am not sure why it happens, but if someone else does I will happily edit my answer to include it.

You will need to specifically tell it to write the output to the console. There are a couple ways of doing this.

The first, and probably messiest, would be to pass it as a parameter to `Write-Host` or `Write-Output`.

```bsh
Write-Host (Get-CimInstance Win32_Processor | Select-Object -Property NumberOfCores)
Write-Host (Get-CimInstance Win32_Processor | Measure-Object -Property LoadPercentage -Sum | Select-Object Sum)
```

(Another way of doing this would be to assign them both to variables, and pass the variables to the cmdlet)

The second way would be to pipe it to `Write-Host` or `Write-Output`

```bsh
Get-CimInstance Win32_Processor | Select-Object -Property NumberOfCores | Write-Host
Get-CimInstance Win32_Processor | Measure-Object -Property LoadPercentage -Sum | Select-Object Sum | Write-Host
```

And finally, the third (and in my opinion cleanest) way would be to pipe it to a code block that references the property directly

```bsh
Get-CimInstance Win32_Processor | %{$_.NumberOfCores}
Get-CimInstance Win32_Processor | Measure-Object -Property LoadPercentage -Sum | %{$_.Sum}
```

Hope this helps!