# Converting XLSX to CSV with ImportExcel missing Columns in Powershell

Tags: excel, powershell, csv

I am converting files with the `Import-Excel` module in Powershell with this simple code:

```
Import-Excel -Path $PSScriptRoot\*.xlsx | Export-Csv $PSScriptRoot\file.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

The problem is this file has only two columns with data:

> `Articleno`  and `Quantity`

When the quantity is `0` (zero) in the first row, the module just exports the first column to csv; the `Quantity` column is completely ignored.

What am I doing wrong? Why does `Import-Excel` not export the `0` as well?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Not all properties displayed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44428189/not-all-properties-displayed)

Comment: Actually, if it is indeed related to the above mentioned question, I would qualify it as a [`Import-Excel`](https://github.com/dfinke/ImportExcel) bug as it should have property defined as well in the first row even it but is zero or null.

Comment: I am not able to reproduce your issue. Make sure you have the latest version of the `Import-Excel` module. Exclude `Export-Csv` (try default default display output). If the issue persists, I recommend you to raise the issue on the project site of `ImportExcel`: https://github.com/dfinke/ImportExcel

Comment: yeah correct. It seems more like a bug in Import-Excel. I hope the developers are reading here or i will have to make an issue here: https://github.com/dfinke/ImportExcel

Comment: So i updated the module with "Update-Module ImportExcel" to the latest Version in Powershell. When my first row contains a 0 for the quantity this row is not being imported. When i just import it in powershell i just see the first column, The second one is not displayed. When i change the quantity to 1 the second column is displayed.

Comment: I just checked the Version. It is 7.0.1 installed.

Comment: Are you using special cell formating? Can you share the `xlsx` file?

Comment: Well i thought of it as well but there are no formats in the file. I also removed the alignments and checked if the fields of the column have a special format. They are formated as "standard" in excel. The cells have no colors or backgrounds. No special fonts or anything else special about that file. I cannot share the file because of data sensibility. We use this file to check the stocks of a company.

Comment: Can you reproduce it with a fresh `xlsx` and random/ example data (and share that)? Also make sure you exclude add-ons and macros. In other words,, please try to create a [mcve].

Comment: @iRon sure here is a very simple test and it also does not import the column as explained: https://mega.nz/#!OF1AxYha!fUPDiNY_I7e1_9dG59rMrKi2MpJh3dwiDaq4wzDghQA

Here is also a Screenshot so you can see what happens at my Powershell:
https://mega.nz/#!WUsihQSa!nEjqr9wK0WKBu1mzRYhUNJnRMX1L5wXvj5RNgoZpKLg

Answer (score 0):

ok the Problem is that "ImportExcel" always expects a header in the first row. When you use the "-NoHeader" Tag everything works fine and the 0 in the first row will be imported.