# Iterating through JSON objects with missing tags using powershell

Tags: json, powershell, rest

**Background** : I'm trying to iterate through a REST API response and use the information to populate a mysql database. My problem is that some of the objects are missing tags so  the data doesn't align correctly with my current script .

**Example of JSON** : In this example , espl002 is missing the primary IP address tag.

```
 {
  "cis" : [ {
    "udbId" : "40000c5e6b84af5588aa066a1569b17e",
    "globalId" : "40000c5e6b84af5588aa066a1569b17e",
    "type" : "netprinter",
    "properties" : {
      "discovered_vendor" : "Fuji Xerox",
      "name" : "xrx9c934e19ffa5",
      "global_id" : "40000c5e6b84af5588aa066a1569b17e",
      "primary_ip_address" : "182.19.323.23"
    }
      }, {
    "udbId" : "400050e64747c97b80a41358b7810c29",
    "globalId" : "400050e64747c97b80a41358b7810c29",
    "type" : "netprinter",
    "properties" : {
      "discovered_vendor" : "Fuji Xerox",
      "name" : "phaser 4510n",
      "global_id" : "400050e64747c97b80a41358b7810c29",
      "primary_ip_address" : "182.19.323.21"
    }
   }, {
    "udbId" : "4ffc72d7151c94ae850837effb45f3c2",
    "globalId" : "4ffc72d7151c94ae850837effb45f3c2",
    "type" : "netprinter",
    "properties" : {
      "discovered_vendor" : "Fuji Xerox",
      "name" : "espl002",
      "global_id" : "4ffc72d7151c94ae850837effb45f3c2",
    }
  } ],
  "relations" : null
}
```

**Current code being used :**

```
[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Web.Extensions")  
[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom(“C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector Net 8.0.20\Assemblies\v4.5.2\MySql.Data.dll”)
$token ="eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGl0b3J5IjoiVUNNREIiLCJleHAiOjE1ODk4MjgyNzUsImN1c3RvbWVyIjoxLCJ1c2VybmFtZSI6Im1zaW5naCJ9.AsOXTrVu8BIU2XUfk7_fxbMkwhylvBTsRHJ-imuP0mk"
#Total Printers
 $params = @{
    Uri         = 'https://test.ca/rest-api/topology'
    Headers     = @{ 'Authorization' = "Bearer $token" }
    Method      = 'POST'
    Body        = 'totalprinters'
    ContentType = 'application/json'
    Outfile     = 'C:\Users\test\Desktop\API\TOTALPRINTERS.json'
}
Invoke-RestMethod @params 
$json  = Get-Content -Raw -Path C:\Users\test\Desktop\API\TOTALPRINTERS.json
$jsonserial = New-Object -TypeName System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer
$jsonserial.MaxJsonLength = [int]::MaxValue
$Obj = $jsonserial.DeserializeObject($json)
$Totalprinters= $obj.cis.properties.global_id.count   #Total printers count 
$limit = $obj.cis.properties.global_id.count
$Connection = New-Object MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection
$ConnectionString = “server=187.15.43.434;uid=test;pwd=CM123$;database=test;pooling=false”
$Connection.ConnectionString = $ConnectionString
$Connection.Open()

$datasend = For ($i = 0; $i -lt $limit; $i++) {
$nameofprinter=$obj.cis.properties.name[$i]
$ipofprinter=$obj.cis.properties.primary_ip_address[$i]
$manufacturerofprinter=$obj.cis.properties.discovered_vendor[$i]
$Query = "INSERT INTO printers (name,ip,manufacturer, Divison) VALUES ('$nameofprinter','$ipofprinter','$manufacturerofprinter',' ')" 
$Command = New-Object MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand($Query, $Connection)
$DataAdapter = New-Object MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataAdapter($Command)
$DataSet = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
$RecordCount = $dataAdapter.Fill($dataSet, "data")

}
```

**Attempt at Solution** : From some research , I believe assigning the objects to a hash table would solve my issue then sending this data over to the mysql database. Unfortunately, I'm still learning powershell and not quite sure how to do this in this example.

Comment: Why not using [`ConvertFrom-Json`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-json?view=powershell-7)?

Comment: This [`Union-Object`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44429084/1701026) might help you to align the properties.

Comment: @iRon , I had covertfrom-json before but the actual rest api responses are too big to use it . Will take a look at Union-Object

Comment: Is this a single REST response or multiple? (How large is a single response?) If it concerns multiple objects, did you try to stream each object by properly using the PowerShell pipeline (rather than collecting all PowerShell objects into memory)?

Comment: @iRon its a single REST response , about 10 mb with over 10000 lines

Comment: You could try `$ipofprinter=$obj.cis.properties.primary_ip_address[$i]; if (!$ipofprinter) { $ipofprinter = 'NULL' }`

Comment: @Theo , I tried your suggestion . There is now an entry for everything , but it doesn't align correctly with the rest api response . Null values were placed at last rows in the database table instead of entries that don't have any ip

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help everyone , I wasn't streaming each object properly . Modified script and used a hashtable .

```
[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [System.Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls13  
[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Web.Extensions")  
[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom(“C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector Net 8.0.20\Assemblies\v4.5.2\MySql.Data.dll”)
$Connection = New-Object MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection
$ConnectionString = “server=199.32.3.3;uid=test;pwd=CM$;database=test;pooling=false”
$Connection.ConnectionString = $ConnectionString
$Connection.Open()

$json  = Get-Content -Raw -Path "C:\Users\test\Desktop\API\TOTALPRINTERS.json"

$jsonParts = $json -split "udbId"" :"

for ($part_Index = 1;$part_Index -lt $jsonParts.Length;$part_Index++)
{
$jsonPart = $jsonParts[$part_Index]
$name = ($jsonPart -split """name"" :")[1]
$name = ($name -split """")[1]
$name=$name -replace("'","")

$ip = ($jsonPart -split """primary_ip_address"" :")[1]
$ip = ($ip -split """")[1]

$manufacturer = ($jsonPart -split """discovered_vendor"" :")[1]
$manufacturer = ($manufacturer -split """")[1]

$Division = ""

$Query="INSERT INTO printers(name,ip,manufacturer,Divison) VALUES('$name','$ip','$manufacturer','$Divison')"
$Command = New-Object MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand($Query, $Connection) 
$DataAdapter = New-Object MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataAdapter($Command) 
$DataSet = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
$RecordCount = $dataAdapter.Fill($dataSet, "data")
}
```