# Powershell hash tables not multiplying

Tags: powershell, hashtable

I'm doing a very basic script of sorting an employee CSV file, and renaming a couple of the fields.  Easy stuff, but now I'm supposed to add a column at the end and show what the employee's 6% bonus would be.  So I'm using this entry:

```
@{label='Bonus';expression={$_.Salary * .06}}
```

However..it just returns nothing.  The field is blank.  If I change it to show the bonus plus the salary...

```
@{label='BonusSalary';expression={$_.Salary * 1.06}}
```

It returns the Salary value, like I multiplied by one.  Now if I change the operator to anything OTHER than multiplication, it works fine.

Can someone point me in the right direction to find out why it's doing this?

Comment: Please create a [mcve], I guess this is your issue: [not all properties displayed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44429084/1701026) but there aren't enough details to confirm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming this is the situation, where the left argument is a string.  In that case, powershell will repeat the string that many times.  The right arg actually becomes an integer.  If you reverse the arguments, it will convert the right argument to a double or floating point.  When you import a csv, all fields are strings.  It would be different with a json file.

```
'1.0' * .06


.06 * '1.0'
0.06


'hi' * 3
hihihi


'1.0' * 3
1.01.01.0


[double]'10.00' * .06
0.6
```

Comment: You're amazing!  I didn't think to flop the two because I didn't know what it was doing internally.  Thank you for the explanation!