# populate an empty array from with in a foreach-object loop and export CSV

Tags: powershell, powershell-7.0

I  finally  got the functionality of  my script working  now   I want to  save to CSV, Im using the `| Export-CSV -path .\output.csv -Delimiter ";"`. but not able to get the data  i need.

I'm creating a global  empty array    and   trying to append items  within in a `foreach-object` loop
but get an  empty  CSV

im also runing  my `foraech-object` as  a job  and   piping the  `| Export-CSV -path .\output.csv -Delimiter ";"` and  get   a random  set of numbers

how can i get  my data in to CSV?

**My Script**

```
Function Get-FileName{
    [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName(“System.windows.forms”) | Out-Null
    $OpenFileDialog = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog
    $OpenFileDialog.initialDirectory = Get-Location
    $OpenFileDialog.filter = “All files (*.*)| *.*”
    $OpenFileDialog.ShowDialog() | Out-Null
    $OpenFileDialog.filename
}

$Importfile = Get-FileName
$Clients = Get-Content $Importfile

$Do = $Clients | ForEach-Object -Parallel {
    # CHECK IF  PC IS IN AD  AND  STATUS  OF  PC IN AD   ENABLED/DISABLED
    $O = get-ADComputer -Identity $_ -Properties Enabled
        if ($O."Enabled" -eq 'TRUE') {

            #CHECK IF PC IS  NETWORK ACCESSIBLE 
            if (Test-Connection -ComputerName $_ -Count 2 -Quiet){

                try{ 
                    #GET  LATEST KB PATCH INSTALLED 
                    Get-HotFix -ComputerName $_ -Description 'Security Update' | Select-Object -Last 1 # tried  to get csv from here  and only capture  what passes through here and not the  catch or elses also tryed appending this to empty array  
                    }
                catch{ 
                    "$_;An error occurred." 
                }  
            }
            else{
                "$_;not on line "
            }
        } 
        else{
            "$_;Disabled PC"
        } 
} -AsJob 

$Do | Receive-Job -Wait   # i tried  " | Export-CSV -path .\output.csv -Delimiter ";" " and  got random  data
```

Comment: the `Foreach-Object -Parallel` command is not available unless you are ps7+. you say that you are using ps3 ... so, are you getting any errors from that wrong usage? [*grin*] ///// also, using `$Job` for a variable name is somewhat misleading in that there are PSJob cmdlets. i _strongly_ recommend you NEVER use keywords or special purpose cmdlet nouns for variable names.

Comment: Hey Lee_Dailey.  I forgot to mentioned yesterday i upgraded to PS 7.01 and will change my variable names. I was not aware JOB was a key word ... just learning PS without formal study its more as hands on, on things because it needs to be done. thanks for the correction

Comment: `job` aint a keyword ... it is a fairly specific noun used in the `*-Job` cmdlets. using it for a $Var name can lead to confusion when folks read it and think ... "i don't see anything to do with jobs ...". [*grin*] ///// please REMOVE the ps3 tag and add the ps7 tag so that folks won't be confused by your tags.

Comment: Done !  Thanks. You wouldn’t happen to know PS 7 ???

Comment: thanks! unfortunately, i still haven't gone into ps7 at this time. i don't see anything obviously wrong with your code, tho. ///// i would likely switch to using `Invoke-Command` since you can give it a scriptblock and a list of target systems ... and it will run the scriptblock on each system in parallel. you can also catch the non-responders with `-ErrorVariable` or by comparing the responders to the target list.

Comment: You need to stream a (list of) [`[pscustomobject]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/deep-dives/everything-about-pscustomobject?view=powershell-7.1) rather than a `[String]` which is required for the [`Export-Csv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/export-csv?view=powershell-7.1) input.

Comment: @iRon I'm actually kinda  new to PS  and  PS scripting   and   English is not my native lang.     Do you have a link to  a resource  I can  learn  what you are talking about or can you explain in  simpler terms please

Comment: @Lee_Dailey Unfortunately  to run  `Invoke-Command` requires  WinRm to be enabled on  client PC.  Which is not  and  would have to enable  service  manually  since network admin  will not  create  a GPO  ... with the  current  script  im  able to get   the result  i want  but fail to create  CSV the  closets  i have gotten  is  by  doing this  `Get-HotFix -ComputerName $_ -Description 'Security Update' | Select-Object -Last | Export-Csv -path .\OutputFile.csv -Delimiter ";"`   but it only captures  in the CSV  the records  that  fall in that IF condition  and not the errors or offlines ..

Comment: @Lee_Dailey As  I mentioned, I tried creating  a global empty  array  and tried to append  data to array   depending  on  what  condition was met  and on the end of the  script  tried pushing that to the CSV file,  but  array  never  populated info

Comment: @victorR - take a look at this >>> `Get-Help New-CimSessionOption -Parameter protocol` <<< and this >>> `Get-Help Invoke-Command -Parameter session` <<< //// that means you can use DCOM instead of WSMan. if you can use the WMI cmdlets to access those systems ... then you can use `Invoke-Command` via `New-CimSession`. [*grin*]

Comment: @Lee_Dailey well  it  did connect  to  remote host  however I'm not able to run 'invoke-command' . `cim-session` and `invoke-method` are a new monster i  need to research ... can you provide  an example of runing  `invoke-command`  though cimsession please

Comment: @victorR - use `New-CimSessionOption` to set the protocol. then use `New-CimSession` to create the sessions to all [or a group of] the targets. next, use the `-Session` parameter of `Invoke-Command` to tell it to use the collection of sessions as needed. last, feed the scriptblock to the `I-C` call. that otta do it. i don't currently have anything to test this on ... just my one home system.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey  I've tried that and  thi is  what  i got  `" Invoke-Command -session $ses {get-hotfix}
Invoke-Command: Cannot bind parameter 'Session'. Cannot convert the "CimSession: PC-w032" value of type "Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.CimSession" to type "System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.PSSession"`.  this was after  i created a new  cimsession  with DCOM  protocol

Comment: @victorR - i see that iRon has posted a working Answer. since i don't have any way to test the CIMSession problems, i suggest letting that go and using the working solution iRon presented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As "*kinda new to PS*" person, I recommend you to take a few steps back and simplify things along with removing the `-Parallel` switch which might obscure the output.
As commented, the [`Export-Csv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/export-csv?view=powershell-7.1) cmdlet requires a stream of *only* [`[pscustomobject]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/scripting/learn/deep-dives/everything-about-pscustomobject) items, you can't combine this with strings (like `"$_;An error occurred."`) or ***an object with different properties***.
See: [Not all properties displayed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44428189/not-all-properties-displayed) and [`#13906` Add -UnifyProperties parameter to Select-Object](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/13906)

```
function UniteProperties { # https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/13906#issuecomment-717480544
  [System.Collections.Generic.List[string]] $propNames = @()
  [System.Collections.Generic.HashSet[string]] $hashSet = @()
  $inputCollected = @($input)
  $inputCollected.ForEach({ 
    foreach ($name in $_.psobject.Properties.Name) {
      if ($hashSet.Add($name)) { $propNames.Add($name) }
    }
  })
  $inputCollected | Select-Object $propNames
}
```

```
$Do = 2, 3, 0, 5 | ForEach-Object -Parallel {
    Try {
        [pscustomobject]@{ Name = "Client$_"; HotFix = 1/$_ } # some standard HotFix results
    }
    Catch {
        [pscustomobject]@{ message = "$_;An error occurred." }
    }
}
$Do | UniteProperties | ConvertTo-Csv # Or ... Export-Csv
```

```
"Name","HotFix","message"
"Client2","0.5",
"Client3","0.3333333333333333",
,,"Attempted to divide by zero.;An error occurred."
"Client5","0.2",
```